# Внесение данных из переменной в fsm aiogram

Tags: aiogram

Как можно организовать внесение данных в fsm не дожидаясь ответа от пользователя. Допустим первым я хочу внести данные о user которые у меня хранятся в переменной, следующие тоже данные из переменной, дальше уже ждать ответ от пользователя.
У меня есть 2 переменные с данными и я хочу внести данные в state не дожидаясь ответа пользователя, как только эти переменные внесены, идёт следующий state на который необходимо ответить. Только данные мне необходимо внести в той функции которая переводит бота в машинное состояние.

```
 @dp.message_handler(commands=['Загрузить'], state=None)
async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
if message.from_user.id == ID:
    await FSMAdmin.category.set()
    ?????????
```

Comment: Так, погодите, вы хотите ДО какого-либо сообщения от юзера добавлять данные в стейт? Вы ведь можете это сделать в том хендлере который у вас запускает стейт. Не понимаю в чем проблема. Даже в вашем примере вам ничего не мешает открыть state.proxy() и записать в него данные о юзере.

Comment: Я хочу внести данные не из сообщения, а из своей переменной, и хочу это сделать перед ответом пользователя на другой вопрос. Когда бота перевожу в машинное состаяние. То есть я после set могу прописать async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['id'] = id.   Или я должен сначало объявить state id занести в него информацию и тут же вызвать второй state с категорией?

Comment: Вот так должно быть? @dp.message_handler(commands=['Загрузить'], state=None)
async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
if message.from_user.id == ID:
    await FSMAdmin.id.set()
    await state.update_date(id = id)
    await FSMAdmin.text.set()
    await state.update_date(text=text)
    await FSMAdmin.category.set()
    await message.reply("Введите категорию"